# Intellij IDEA editing gradle project file vs project settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

It took a few tries to figure out that the way gradle integration works, is by Intellij scanning the gradle project file, and then creating the project settings from it. What was confusing me, and is still confusing me, is how the IDE fails to pick up certain things. It also seems to spontaneously change things like the src directory. I end up having to go in to the project settings, and fix things like marking the appropriate directory as a source directory, and re-adding the excluded source directories. It seems to ignore the exclude statement from the gradle file.
Am I going about this the right way? Why does my project build fine from the command line using the gradlew command, but often does not inside the IDE? Is it normal having to "fix" various project settings? Are these bugs or incomplete features in Intellij?

Comment: In File > Settings > Gradle you can configure which gradle installation should be used. I have set this to "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)". This works perfectly with a large multi-module build.  The project uses gradle wrapper 4.0.2. My IDE version is Intellij 2017.2.

Comment: I'm using 2017.1. Gradle wrapper is... well, ./gradlew ends up saying it's 2.13.
Settings says it's using default gradle wrapper. I don't think it's gradle that is showing these problems. It seems the IDE is the one that fails to interpret and update from the gradle file properly. In fact, it literally seems stupid buggy. I can't figure out why people aren't complaining about this all over the map. It's kind of almost never working properly, that bad.

Comment: Another peculiarity is that ~/.gradle has about 640MB worth of files in it, what gives...

Comment: I just checked mine; It is 4.5GB. There are about 17 Gradle distributions in it. I

Comment: What is your "auto-import" setting in Intellij for this project? If it is enabled it might be worth a try to turn it off and see if Intellij still spontanously changes the project configuration. If this is not the case, try to reimport the project using the "Refresh all Gradle projects" action from the Gradle panel and check whether this causes any unexpected changes.

Comment: I've tried turning off auto import. Manually importing from the "tip" that the IDE shows, or using "refresh all gradle projects", accomplishes the same thing.
After experimenting more, all methods end up importing srcDirs ok, but it ignores "excludes".
ps. I can imagine countless of people being totally confused about the whole notion how the IDE overwrites (some) of its project settings from the gradle file. I too thought at first that the gradle file is something that is generated when changing stuff in the IDE. The IDE is missing warning and notes and such. Bad design. And incomplete.

Comment: I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gradle-dev/9F0jhc-xBH4
This problem went from at least 2014 to now, and appears still not supported. Someone went through the effort of implementing it, but never made it mainstream it seems.

Comment: I think the rationale for purposely not supporting importing the complete source set (with excludes), is because it might be too common for people to require manually wanting to override excluding of unwanted components, notably large binaries and such.
Anyway, I can live with it. I'll just have to manually duplicate excludes in the IDE.
The other problems with the gradle integration I'll have to create entries for with specifics.
The take away here, is the gradle-to-IDE flow of information direction (stunningly un-obvious), and how excludes are excluded from it, creating more confusion.

Comment: Do you use Gradle's [idea plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)? I have never used this one. I always use "Create a new project from existing source" in Intellij and then choose to import the project from the external Gradle model. That way Intellij creates its project files itself.

Comment: Create a new idea project every single time you want to change something in the gradle file? Not that I'd do that that often.

Comment: No, I meant that I use Intellij directly for the initial import instead of creating the Intellij project with the Gradle's idea plugin first. Once, the project is imported in Intellij, I rely on the "auto-import" function of Intellij to reimport it every time the gradle file changed. What wanted to say is that the whole Intellij project creation stuff is done by Intellij and not the Gradle plugin